# How old is Naruto in Boruto series?

Tags: naruto, boruto

Naruto failed the graduation exams three times at the academy before he could graduate (performing the transformation/clone jutsu).

Does this mean he is three years older than his comrades from the academy? So, in *Boruto*, what would his current age be?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer is 27.
I got it simply by googling "Naruto age in boruto"

Comment: Thank you, but the next replies say that he could be 32, because Boruto is 8 years old, some say 31, some say 28-32, mid 20s, 32-33. It seems that the real answer is not clear, but thank you anyways. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say after the end of The Fourth Ninja World War, Naruto is 17 years old. Then, in The Last: Naruto the Movie, it's stated that the event occurred after 2 years.  You can rever to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last:_Naruto_the_Movie.

Then sure, Naruto married after that, let's say it takes several months for marriage preparation, and Naruto married at the age of 20, and Boruto is born 1 year later at Naruto age 21.

Now in Boruto: Naruto Next Generation series, Boruto is already graduated from the academy and as a gennin. The common age of a ninja who graduated from the academy is 12 years old. Many things happen after Boruto become a gennin, and let's say his age is 13.

So Naruto's age now in Boruto: Naruto Next Generation series is about 21 + 13 = 34 years old.